# How to tell when CLLocationManager has a lock on the users location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

If CLLocationManager semi working in my app. I start the locationManager, set the delegate, and accuracy. But once the location manager starts my map shows me in some ocean?

Is there a way to know when CLLocationManager has a lock?

I have the following method setup, but it doesn't get called unless I walk a few steps.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I have verified that its all running on the main thread.

Comment: Many times I ended up in the ocean myself, and it was always cause I switched longitude and latitude while presenting location in map, so check that, check your accuracy and do it on real device (just in case you are using simulator...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the `CLLocation` objects you receive in `didUpdateLocations`. On a device, when you first start location services, you'll often notice a series of locations coming in with decreasing `horizontalAccuracy` values (i.e. more and more accurate location values). It's not a question of when it "locks in", but rather when do you receive a location with a `horizontalAccuracy` that is sufficiently small for your app's purposes.

In terms of the method not getting called until you move, that is generally a function of what `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` values you use.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like **lock** in CLLocationManager ,

It depends on properties that you have set for your location manager,

check these properties of your location manager

**distanceFilter** : The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.

**desiredAccuracy** : The accuracy of the location data.

You can check location service using class method **locationServicesEnabled** for checking whether location services are enabled on the device.